# Update query sql deletes content of other fields from database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, oop

I have a database with a tblUsers with following fields
1. DiaryLighton | DiaryLichtoff | DiarySleep | DiaryAwake | FeedbackUser | FeedbackDoctor

When I'm on the diary-page I need to fill in the DiaryLighton | DiaryLightoff | DiarySleep | DiaryAwake after clicking the save button. The same should happen on the Feedback - page. After clicking the button the FeedbackUser | FeedbackDoctor should be filled in.

**Problem however is, that it saves the data, but when I save the diary after saving the feedback, the content of the feedback disappears out of the table and the other way around.**

Someone any clue? Here's the code. Thanks!

Save the diary:

```
public function saveDay($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open connection to database

    $sql="UPDATE tblDiary
                     SET
                          DiaryLichtAan = '".$this->Aanuur."',
                          DiaryLichtUit = '".$this->Uituur."',
                          DiaryOpstaan = '".$this->Opstaan."',
                          DiaryGaanSlapen = '".$this->Slapen."'
                     WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."
                     and DiaryDay = '".$this->Day."';"; 
    try
    {
        $link->query($sql); 
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();   
    }   

    mysqli_close($link); //close connection with database
}
```

AJAX:

```
$(".submitbutton").click( function() {
    var aanuur = $(".onzichtbaar_aan").val();
    var uituur = $(".onzichtbaar_uit").val();               
    var opstaan = $(".onzichtbaar_opstaan").val();
    var slapen = $(".onzichtbaar_slapen").val();
    var feeling = $("#onzichtbaar_feeling").val();
    var day = $(".confirmday").val();

    $.post("ajax/save.php", {lichtaan: aanuur, 
                            lichtuit: uituur, 
                            slapen: slapen, 
                            opstaan: opstaan, 
                            feeling: feeling,
                            userid: <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>,
                            day: day},
            function(data) {
    });
    return false;
});
```

Save the feedback:

```
public function saveFeedbackP($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php");

    try
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE tblDiary
                SET 
                    DiaryOpmerkingen = '".$this->Patientfb."'
                WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid." 
                AND DiaryDay = ".$this->Day.";";
        $rResult = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        return $rResult;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: Is it in the database correctly ever? In other words, if you check the results after the 1st save but before the 2nd, is it correct? It sounds like you are not committing your changes.

Comment: @MJB Yeah, if I save the Diary.. everything from the diary comes in the db perfectly. If I save the feedback, everything comes in the db perfectly. But the other saved part disappears.. It's really weird.

Comment: And you are positive that there is only one table involved, right? There is no schema difference to worry about? One script being run by a user and one by an admin, for example?

Comment: Just one. One user does the input in one table.

Comment: What about the row count in the table? Is it what you expect it to be, before and after each of the inserts? Are there lots of rows, so that it would be easy to miss the changes? Or are there only a few, maybe 10 rows, so there is no chance you are looking at the wrong rows?

Comment: I have a table with 14 rows. But I'm positive I'm not looking at the wrong rows. I just update the top one, so it's easy to recognize. Strange thing is that when I update the feedback, the diaryvalues stay in the db, the other way around, they go away. I think the problem is in the ajax..

Comment: Could be. But in my experience, when you troubleshoot your own code, you tend to look at the part where you think it is -- as opposed to all of the possibilities. So I figured start at the most basic and see if your assumptions are indeed correct (that is really is working, but overwriting each separate update).

Answer (score 0):

My 1st assumption is that your SQL is ok, but your feedback code somehow calls after saveDay with empty value, that overwrite everything.

Just try to **LOG** all your sql updates and you will see the root of the problem.